# Create .mm file in xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9.1

I am unable to create .mm file in Xcode 9.1. When I add file and select c file it create .m file and when I select c++ then it create .cpp file. please suggest me how to create .mm file in Xcode 9.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to change the extension to .mm. There is no option to create a file with .mm extension in Xcode. Refer [this](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/how-to-create-new-class-with-mm-file/17095/2).

Comment: which file formate I will select and rename (c or c++) in Xcode

Comment: That doesn't matter. Any file created if renamed as .mm will do for you. I prefer renaming a .m file as I just need to add one m. I'm a bit lazy ;P
To be specific, prefer .m file as it would have pre-added objective-c code and you will need to add only cpp code.